# How to make a link display a particular data from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a product website for my final project and I want to make a link that will for example (if I click on processors on the webpage, it will display only a list of processors form my database on another page. Same should happen when I click on other categories like motherboard, graphics card, etc). For instance I made a button with a method post then on the other page I wrote the following codes:

**parts.php**

```
    <form action="display.php" method="post">


        <div class="partbox">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="./img/processor.jpg" alt="Go to Processor">
            </a>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btnlink" value="Processor" name="processor"</input>
        </div>

        <div class="partbox">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="./img/motherboard.jpg" alt="Go to Motherboard">
            </a>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btnlink" value="Motherboard" name="motherboard"</input>
        </div>
```

etc...

**display.php**

```
//When Clicking on Processor

if(isset($_POST['processor'])){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = 'Processor' ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "<h1>" . $row["category"] . "</h1>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    include('info.php');
    echo $info;
}
}

//When clicking on Motherboard



if(isset($_POST['motherboard'])){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = 'Motherboard ' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "<h1>" . $row["category"] . "</h1>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    include('info.php');
    echo $info;
}
}
```

etc...

Well, I don't know if this is possible with a link. Or is it ok to keep it like that? I'm afraid that I'm making it too long thinking that there might be an easiest way to do so.

Comment: or you use links (and method is only GET) or you use a form with its elements (select, input) and you can choose the method (GET or POST). You cannot (and there is no reason why) combine the two

Answer (score -1):

parts.php

```
    <div class="partbox">
        <a href="display.php?category_name=Processor">
        <img src="./img/processor.jpg" alt="Go to Processor">
        </a>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class="partbox">
        <a href="display.php?category_name=Motherboard">
        <img src="./img/motherboard.jpg" alt="Go to Motherboard">
        </a>
        <br>
    </div>
```

display.php

```
// based on the link clicked, $_GET['category_name'] will have the 
//values Processor or Motherboard
if(isset($_GET['category_name'])){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = $_GET['category_name'] ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo "<h1>" . $row["category"] . "</h1>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        include('info.php');
        echo $info;
    }
}
```